# Compare and identify new records in Select query for different dates

Tags: sql-server

I have a query as part of a stored procedure and the results are correct. I do however need to add code to compare the results to the results of the same query when it last ran e.g. 2 days ago. I then need any new records that was not on the results from 2 days ago to appear on top (first) in the results. I tried using the Except clause, but the results are wrong.
Any help will be appreciated how to identify any new records compared to the records from GETDATE()-1. Thank you

```
SELECT  distinct rt.sPortfolio, CAST(rt.iRuleId AS VARCHAR(15)) AS iRuleId, sDescription, sComment, rt.sPortfolio AS BlankRow
FROM thinktank..ruletests AS rt
   INNER JOIN thinktank..rules AS r
   ON r.id = rt.iruleid
     AND dttest > getdate()-0.5
     AND iresult <> 4
     AND ichecktype = 3
     AND r.iCategory = 0
     AND sRuleSet <> 'NOTIFY'
   INNER JOIN thinktank..GroupPortfolios AS gp
   ON rt.sPortfolio = gp.sPortfolioId
     AND sGroupID = 'EC'
   LEFT OUTER JOIN thinktank..RuleUCs AS ruc
   ON r.id = ruc.iruleid 
     AND ruc.icategory = '636'
   WHERE ISNULL(ruc.sValue,'N') <> 'Y'

EXCEPT

SELECT  distinct rt.sPortfolio, CAST(rt.iRuleId AS VARCHAR(15)) AS iRuleId, sDescription, sComment, rt.sPortfolio AS BlankRow
FROM thinktank..ruletests AS rt
    INNER JOIN thinktank..rules AS r
    ON r.id = rt.iruleid
      AND dttest > getdate()-1
      AND iresult <> 4
      AND ichecktype = 3
      AND r.iCategory = 0
      AND sRuleSet <> 'NOTIFY'
    INNER JOIN thinktank..GroupPortfolios AS gp
    ON rt.sPortfolio = gp.sPortfolioId
      AND sGroupID = 'EC'
    LEFT OUTER JOIN thinktank..RuleUCs AS ruc
    ON r.id = ruc.iruleid 
      AND ruc.icategory = '636'
    WHERE ISNULL(ruc.sValue,'N') <> 'Y'
```

Comment: mysql does not have a getdate() function, so removed the mysql tag.

Comment: `ISNULL(ruc.sValue,'N') <> 'Y'` syntax like this isn't SARGable. Explicitly check for `NULL` as well or (if you're on SQL Server 2022) use `IS DISTINCT FROM`.

Comment: I would avoid those date shortcuts if it were me. They are funky to say the least. It would be more clear to use DATEADD. Not to mention that if you change your datatype to datetime2 it will suddenly fail.

Comment: For the question at hand you have a couple things going on here. First if you want rows to be in a certain order in a result set you need to use an `ORDER BY` clause. It sounds like you need to use another query to get the data from two days ago and then use a left join to see if it is new or not. Without table structures, sample data and desired output it is nearly impossible to help much.

Comment: I would suggest this. 1. Create temp table that should hold today and 2 days ago data and a flag that says if it's today's data or yesterday. 2. Right now, you select same columns with only difference is two different dates. You can instead use *one* select and do a  dttest > getdate()-1 and then just a case when flag depending on dttest. 3. EXCEPT only returns rows from the first Select, EXCEPT if they exist in second SELECT. It doesn't return rows in second select that dont' exist in first. One usually use FULL OUTER JOIN to do this between today's and yesterday's rows

Comment: 3. ... Continued. Alternatively you use Select 1 EXCEPT SELECT 2 UNION ALL SELECT 2 EXCEPT SELECT 2, to get all diffing rows. My personal opinion is that EXCEPT is seldom useful, because one sometimes want to sort etc based on some flag, but existance of flag ruins the EXCEPT because flag is always different :)

Comment: `getdate()-0.5`, `getdate()-1`? Why the creative date math? Have you tried `dateadd(hour, -12, getdate())`, etc., so it's explicit what you're doing and not relying on what you think you know about the underlying storage type?